# SSL handshake error javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException Received fatal alert bad_certificate

Tags: java, ssl, ssl-certificate, sslhandshakeexception, jsse

I am executing the below cURL command and I am getting proper response from the server:

```
 curl -k --cert ./xevias.com.crt --key ./xevias.com.key --pass USSEQUX90 --cacert ./xeviasqamts.ca -H "Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8" -H "SOAPAction:\"ws:performTransaction\"" -d @performTransaction.xml -X POST https://xevias.com:8481/DEV/PerformTransaction
```

Now to do the same through my CXF soap webClient I am getting below exception:

```
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: SSLHandshakeException invoking https://xevias.com:8481/DEV/PerformTransaction.jws: Received fatal alert: bad_certificate
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
        at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit$WrappedOutputStream.mapException(HTTPConduit.java:1338)
        at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit$WrappedOutputStream.close(HTTPConduit.java:1322)
        at org.apache.cxf.transport.AbstractConduit.close(AbstractConduit.java:56)
        at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit.close(HTTPConduit.java:622)
        at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.MessageSenderInterceptor$MessageSenderEndingInterceptor.handleMessage(MessageSenderInterceptor.java:62)
        at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:271)
        at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.doInvoke(ClientImpl.java:530)
        at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:463)
        at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:366)
        at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:319)
        at org.apache.cxf.frontend.ClientProxy.invokeSync(ClientProxy.java:96)
        at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.JaxWsClientProxy.invoke(JaxWsClientProxy.java:133)
        ... 66 more
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: bad_certificate
        at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:174)
        at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:136)
        at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.recvAlert(SSLSocketImpl.java:1839)
        at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1019)
        at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1203)
        at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1230)
        at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1214)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.afterConnect(HttpsClient.java:434)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:166)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getOutputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1014)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getOutputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:230)
        at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.URLConnectionHTTPConduit$URLConnectionWrappedOutputStream.setupWrappedStream(URLConnectionHTTPConduit.java:168)
        at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit$WrappedOutputStream.handleHeadersTrustCaching(HTTPConduit.java:1282)
        at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit$WrappedOutputStream.onFirstWrite(HTTPConduit.java:1233)
        at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.URLConnectionHTTPConduit$URLConnectionWrappedOutputStream.onFirstWrite(URLConnectionHTTPConduit.java:195)
        at org.apache.cxf.io.AbstractWrappedOutputStream.write(AbstractWrappedOutputStream.java:47)
        at org.apache.cxf.io.AbstractThresholdOutputStream.write(AbstractThresholdOutputStream.java:69)
        at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit$WrappedOutputStream.close(HTTPConduit.java:1295)
        ... 76 more
```

I have imported the certificate for the host xevias.com:8481 into my keyStore using the below command:

```
keytool -import -keystore $JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/security/cacerts -file xevias.com.crt -alias sslkey
```

Please let me know how can I import certificates with keys, so that all which are there in the cURL command can be installed in the respective places.

Answer (score 1):

Could you try importing Root certificate to your keystore file.

You could use following command to do that. 
keytool -import -alias "alias" -keystore "your_keystore_filename" -trustcacerts -file "filename_of_the_root"

Answer (score -1):

You have to check that your cert has the proper info, you should check that the CN of your client cert has the same name as the server:

**CN=com.app.local**

After that with this command you can import you p12 to your JKS

***keytool -v -importkeystore -srckeystore C:\your_location\tour_file.p12 -srcstoretype PKCS12 -destkeystore d:\cert\your_store.jks -deststoretype JKS***

hope it helps

Comment: and since this asker has client key and cert in separate PEM files, first use openssl to put them in a p12: `openssl pkcs12 -export -in my.crt -inkey my.key -out my.p12` (man pkcs12 or http://www.openssl.org/docs/apps/pkcs12.html for more options)

Comment: There is no requirement that the client CN is the same as the server's.